# nestjs-sequelize not syncing with any modle after implementing sesstion store

Tags: mysql, typescript, discord, sequelize.js, nestjs

So I'm making a discord bot and a website dashboard for it. I got everything working except the backend Nestjs API I'm making.
My Bot uses Sequelize as its database so I thought I would do the same for my API. I really don't want to switch to any other ORM.

All my API code can be found at: https://github.com/Sideways-Sky/api

For some reason, my API won't sync with my MySQL database. It doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't work.
It may be due to the fact that I tried to set up a session store and got something wrong there. (I'm kind of new to Nestjs and I'm not really sure how to properly store a session ) I think the issue is probably in main.ts or app.module.ts. I've spent a whole day just trying to figure this out but nothing online seems to help.

Any and all feedback is greatly welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `autoLoadModels` to be `true`, it should work.